# Instantiation of package for a Generic type is abandoned by compiler in Ada

Tags: instantiation, ada

Ok so I trying to run my code which calls a package dirforinv.adb:

```
WITH  Text_IO;
WITH  Ada.Numerics.Generic_Real_Arrays;
WITH  Ada.Numerics.Generic_Elementary_functions;
WITH  Ada.Strings.Fixed;
WITH  dirforinv;
PROCEDURE  levfordir  IS

J : CONSTANT  Integer := 100;

TYPE  Real  IS DIGITS  13;

PACKAGE  Real_IO  IS NEW  Text_IO.Float_IO   (Real);
PACKAGE  Int_IO   IS NEW  Text_IO.Integer_IO (Integer);

TYPE  Gen_arr  IS ARRAY (INTEGER RANGE <>, INTEGER RANGE <>)  OF  Real;
TYPE  var_array  IS ARRAY (INTEGER RANGE <>)  OF  Real;

PACKAGE  Real_arrays  IS NEW Ada.numerics.Generic_Real_Arrays (Real);
USE      Real_arrays;
PACKAGE  sdirect      IS NEW dirforinv (var_array, Gen_arr);
PACKAGE  Math         IS NEW Ada.numerics.Generic_Elementary_functions (Real);
USE      Math;
```

But I get the following error.

```
  PACKAGE  sdirect      IS NEW dirforinv (var_array, Gen_arr);
                                             |
    >>> expect float type in instantiation of "Real"
    >>> instantiation abandoned
```

I don't understand this as dirforinv expects 5 arrays, 1 of var_array and 4 of Gen_arr. The .ads for dirforinv is below.

```
WITH Profiles,
   Profiles.Inputs,
   Profiles.Conversion,
   Profiles.Provide_Grids,
   Profiles.Multipolar,
   Profiles.Unno_Solver,
   Profiles.Outputs,
   Text_IO, Ada.Numerics.Generic_Elementary_Functions;
USE Profiles;


GENERIC
  TYPE Real  IS DIGITS <>;
  TYPE Gen_arr  IS ARRAY (INTEGER RANGE <>, INTEGER RANGE <>) OF REAL;
  TYPE var_array  IS ARRAY (INTEGER RANGE <>)  OF  REAL;

PACKAGE dirforinv IS

 PROCEDURE direct (Variables                 : IN  var_array;
                   StoI, StoQ, StoU, StoV    : OUT Gen_arr );

END dirforinv;
```

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The declaration of `dirforinv` (horrid name, by the way) is

```
GENERIC
  TYPE Real  IS DIGITS <>;
  TYPE Gen_arr  IS ARRAY (INTEGER RANGE <>, INTEGER RANGE <>) OF REAL;
  TYPE var_array  IS ARRAY (INTEGER RANGE <>)  OF  REAL;

PACKAGE dirforinv IS
```

which has three generic formal parameters; your attempted instantiation is

```
PACKAGE  sdirect      IS NEW dirforinv (var_array, Gen_arr);
```

which only has two.

Comment: The Ada Way would be to call it `Direct_For_Inversion` (I don't understand that either, but workers in the field presumably would!)